# Eclipse: Could not open the editor: No editor descriptor for id org.eclipse.jdt.ui.CompilationUnitEditor

Tags: java, eclipse

When I updated Eclipse using "Help -> Check for Updates" I got a problem.

If I try to start Eclipse, Eclipse opens but show a error message like this:

```
  Could not open the editor: No editor descriptor 
  for id org.eclipse.jdt.ui.CompilationUnitEditor
```

And inside "Details" of the error, I have the following description:

```
    org.eclipse.ui.PartInitException: No editor descriptor for id org.eclipse.jdt.ui.CompilationUnitEditor
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartPane.setVisible(PartPane.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.PresentablePart.setVisible(PresentablePart.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.PresentablePartFolder.select(PresentablePartFolder.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.LeftToRightTabOrder.select(LeftToRightTabOrder.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.TabbedStackPresentation.selectPart(TabbedStackPresentation.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.refreshPresentationSelection(PartStack.java:1245)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.handleDeferredEvents(PartStack.java:1213)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.LayoutPart.deferUpdates(LayoutPart.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartSashContainer.handleDeferredEvents(PartSashContainer.java:1409)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.LayoutPart.deferUpdates(LayoutPart.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.handleDeferredEvents(WorkbenchPage.java:1495)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.deferUpdates(WorkbenchPage.java:1485)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.closeEditors(WorkbenchPage.java:1459)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.closeEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:1514)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorPane.doHide(EditorPane.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.close(PartStack.java:537)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorStack.close(EditorStack.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack$1.close(PartStack.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.TabbedStackPresentation$1.handleEvent(TabbedStackPresentation.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.AbstractTabFolder.fireEvent(AbstractTabFolder.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.AbstractTabFolder.fireEvent(AbstractTabFolder.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.defaultpresentation.DefaultTabFolder.access$1(DefaultTabFolder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.defaultpresentation.DefaultTabFolder$1.closeButtonPressed(DefaultTabFolder.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.PaneFolder.notifyCloseListeners(PaneFolder.java:631)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.PaneFolder$3.close(PaneFolder.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:1598)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1258)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3588)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3209)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2696)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

What can I do to solve this problem? I don't do anything, I just update Eclipse from their own "Check for Updates".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=773132), a workaround for your problem is just move the "~/.eclipse" to another folder.

**So:**

1. Close Eclipse
2. Open "Terminal"
3. Type the following command:

e.g.:

```
mv ~/.eclipse somewhereYouWant
```

When I got this problem, I just:

```
mv ~/.eclipse home/paladini/Downloads
```

Comment: in windows ? 
what to do

Answer (score 13):

Had a similar error when I removed [Eclipse Typescript plugin](https://github.com/palantir/eclipse-typescript)

Tried to open typescript(*.ts) files and got this error:

```
No editor descriptor for id com.palantir.typescript.text.typeScriptEditor
```

And I was not allowed to move the workspace.

On Eclipse Oxygen, Window -> Perspective -> Close All  worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

To resolve this issue, reset the editor to the default configuration:
in eclipse (or STS....) menu bar got to :

```
Windows > Preferences > Editors >: Restore Defaults ; Apply and Close
```

Cordially,

Answer (score 0):

In Windows.

1. Open Eclipse folder
2. Copy all the files and folder in it
3. Paste it to other location
4. Start the Eclipse from the new location
5. Change the workspace location
6. start.

Answer (score 0):

*The other solutions here didn't work for me.*

Perhaps my problem was as the result of trying to get eclipse setup the first time and re-installed different versions of it: a c++ version and then a plain base version + separately installed add-ons.  (Since I also want to use it for other languages I was confused how to set it up.)

**Solution:** I closed eclipse, then renamed: `~/eclipse`, `~/workbench` and `~/.eclipse`;  (in other words, remove them), and finally reinstalled, and restarted.

```
cd ~
mv .eclipse           .eclipse~            #renames
mv  eclipse            eclipse~ 
mv  eclipse-workspace  eclipse-workspace~

~/nobak/Installers/eclipse/eclipse-installer/eclipse-inst    #reinstall

eclipse/cpp-2018-09/eclipse/eclipse   #restart
```

---

My box:

```
OS: GNU/Linux Debian 9.5 (x86-64); 
Cinnamon desktop: 3.2.7; 
Linux Kernel: 4.9.0-8-amd64; 
Processor: Intel Core 2 Duo P8800; 
Graphics Card: AMD/ATI RV710/M92 Mobility Radeon HD 4530/4570/545v
```