# eclipse and android studio dont run together

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I had been using eclipse previously for writing simple Java applications.
Recently I installed Android Studio to learn Android development.
Now, for some reason there seems to be a problem while running eclipse.
The following message appears on the editor of eclipse:

"**No editor descriptor for id org.eclipse.jdt.ui.CompilationUnitEditor**"

Could anyone help me solve the problem? 
I want both the softwares to run on my computer.

Comment: Do you use different directories for eclipse and android studio?

Comment: Yes. The two projects are in seperate locations.

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933348/eclipse-could-not-open-the-editor-no-editor-descriptor-for-id-org-eclipse-jdt

Comment: I did try to change the location of eclipse folder. But the problem isnt solve. I get the error : java.lang.NullPointerException.